# In Maven extensions is it possible to add <configuration> block in the pom.xml like we do for plugins?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-extension

We have a Maven extension which does some post actions at the end of build, but we want to extended its features by adding some flags/properties/something else in `<configuration>` block same as the way we do for plugin configurations in `pom.xml`. Is it possible to do that?

We tried adding it in `pom.xml` but it is throwing exceptions during build, also didn't managed find it in the docs.

Want to have something like below in the `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
  ...
  <extensions>
    ...
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-test-extension</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <configuration>
        ....
      </configuration>
    </extension>
    ...
  </extensions>
  ...
</build>
```

Comment: I suppose there is no possibilty to pass configuration to extensions. A rarely used feature, usually you would use a plugin for that kind of tasks?

Comment: No that's not possible at the moment (see [MNG-5897](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5897)). Can you explain what your extension is doing? Maybe it would be better to implement it as a plugin?

Comment: @GyroGearless @khmarbaise thanks, yes plugin is an another option. Extension is running at the end of build using `afterSessionEnd` and `MavenSession.getAllProjects(), Artifact.getArtifact()`, it list all the artifacts generated in the build. so was wondering if we convert this to plugin is it possible to run it in post same like extensions ?

Comment: For what purpose do you need such information?

Comment: We are generating that info for Clean up process.

Comment: Seems like `<extensions>true</extensions>` is doing the trick here, extension configured as a plugin with `<configuration>` block and it is working as expected.      
    
<build>   
  ...    
  <plugins>    
    ...    
    <plugin>   
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.extensions</groupId>   
      <artifactId>maven-test-extension</artifactId>   
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   
      <extensions>true</extensions>   
      <configuration>   
        ....   
      </configuration>   
    </plugin>   
    ...   
  </plugins>   
  ...
</build>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried it in different way, we have configured the extension as plugin using `<extention>true</extension>` in pom.xml and it accepts the `<configuration>....</configuration>` block.

Comment: Question: from the extension code, how do you get the configuration?

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that this is only for build extensions.
Core extensions are not registered via the pom.xml, so your solution will not work.